# how to split php session variable

Tags: php, session-variables

consider if `$_SESSION['PRICE']` Consist a `value="100 50 10"` as string so i                         want to check 3 checkbox consist of value `100` , `50` and `10`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var price=<?php echo $_SESSION['PRICE']; ?>;// retrieve sessionvariable value and assign to javascript
var priceArray=price.split(" ");
 var i;
  for(i=0;i<count(priceArray);i++){
 $(":checkbox[value=priceArray[i]").attr("checked","true");
 }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it then surrount it with quotes

```
var price= "<?php echo $_SESSION['PRICE']; ?>";// retrieve sessionvariable value and assign to javascript
```

So JS code will be like

```
price = "100 50 10";
var priceArray=price.split(" ");
alert(priceArray[1]);
```

**[Your JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2z9cw8j/)**